# Track downloads on assets

Tags: craft3

I need to figure out if there's a way to track the amount of times an asset was downloaded. I need to display this in the back end on the site. I don't need to display it anywhere but on the back end of an admin user.

Comment: I'm not aware of an existing plugin that does this, but you can use this one as a starting point. It tracks the number of times an entry is viewed. https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-entry-count

Comment: An option would be to use Instant Analytics to send the analytics data on file downloads to Google Analytics where it can be viewed. https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-instantanalytics#tracking-assetsresources